# Air Buddies filming locations?

Tags: film-location, air-buddies

I'm trying to figure out where they filmed [Air Buddies](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0470982/), the spinoff of [Air Bud](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118570/). The most I have been able to find is that it's in British Columbia ([IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0470982/locations?ref_=tt_dt_dt)).

It's really painful because we recently drove through a town in BC that looked exactly like it.

Comment: Air Bud was filmed partly on Vancouver Island - would make sense that the spinoff would too if some of the production team was the same etc...

Comment: So I googled it a bit, and it does look as the entire Air Bud series of movies are filmed (generally) in the same set of locales. So mainly Vancouver, (I do know some parts of the first were on Vancouver Island - not to confuse with)

Comment: @Spacemonkey Thanks for the info. I was so hoping it was an Okanagan winery :)

Comment: it might be, not all locales are listed for the movie series - just the main ones